# Serialize unique form from page of many for AJAX. Works in FF/Safari, but IE serializes ALL forms on page

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, serialization, forms

I have a page of similar items, each in their own form I want to update using Ajax. For each item, I append a counter onto the end of the form id, so each form has a unique id. I also store this "counter id" as an attribute in the submit element, so I can dynamically build the form name in JQuery.

It works **perfectly** in FF win/mac and Safari mac. Serialize obtains only the data from the unique form.

But all versions of IE seem to puke on it...

- For the first form on the page,
  serialize gets all data from
  **every** form on the page
- And for the rest of the forms on the page,
  serialize returns **nothing**

How do I get IE to serialize the proper form, and only that form?

After 3 hours searching google and stackoverflow, I am dead stuck.
Heres a snippet of how the html forms look:

```
    <form id='ajax_multi_form0' action="http://tims-mac-pro.local:8888/configuration/store/node_update" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />     
    ... 
    <input type="text" size='4'name="temperature_below_alert" value='5' /></td> 
    <input type="text" size='4' name="temperature_above_alert" value='26' /></td>
    <input counter='0' class='ajax_multi_submit' type='submit' name="submit" value="Update This Node"       
</form>


<form id='ajax_multi_form1' action="http://tims-mac-pro.local:8888/configuration/store/node_update" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" />     

    <input type="text" size='4'name="temperature_below_alert" value='-10' /></td>   
    <input type="text" size='4' name="temperature_above_alert" value='7' /></td>
    ...     
    <input counter='1' class='ajax_multi_submit' type='submit' name="submit" value="Update This Node"
</form>
```

And here is the JQuery

```
    $('.ajax_multi_submit').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    // get the counter assigned to this form. 
    var element = $(this);
    var counter = element.attr("counter");      

    var formUrl = $('#ajax_multi_form'+counter).attr('action');         

    $.ajax({
            url: formUrl,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: $('#ajax_multi_form'+counter).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                showAjaxMultiBusy(counter);
            },
            complete: function(){
            },
            success: function(html){
                processAjaxMultiForm(html, counter);
            }
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the closing angle bracket on the submit buttons, causing it to misinterpret the closing subsequent closing form tag.

Able to reproduce in IE, and adding the ">" onto the end of those submit buttons made the problem go away...

Comment: Seriously? I shouldn't have assumed that was a typo.

Comment: oh great llama - what a stupid ass i am. Yes - you are right, works fine now.  THANK YOU

Comment: No problemo.  (I assumed it was a copy/paste issue at first too.)